# Python Return Multiple Values so it can be used in another function

Tags: python, function

The easiest way to show this is an example:

```
def hat(a, b):
    return a+b

def cat(c, d):
    return c % 2, d % 2
```

If I type cat(4,5) I properly get (0,1).  However if I try hat(cat(4,5)) instead of getting 1, I get an error saying hat needs more values.  In my real function I am dealing with a lot more than 2 arguments, so what is the proper way to fix this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cat` function actually returns a tuple, when used as an argument to `hat`, it can only match the tuple against the first argument `a`.  You need to expand the tuple into multiple arguments.

Try a call like:

```
hat(*cat(4,5))
```

The `*` will expand the tuple and bind against all the arguments.